# Dependecy injection error on instance controller

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

```js
import {ViaCepService} from "../../services/viacep/viaCepService";

export class ViaCepController {
  private viaCepService: ViaCepService = new ViaCepService()
  async buscarCep(req, reply) {
    return await this.viaCepService.buscarCep(req, reply)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to instanciate my service inside my controller, but doing this using the private word gives me a 500 error on calling the service. For example this image on top doesnt work as well, but if I instanciate the service outside my class like this:

```js
import {ViaCepService} from "../../services/viacep/viaCepService";

const viaCepService: ViaCepService = new ViaCepService()

export class ViaCepController {
  async buscarCep(req, reply) {
    return await viaCepService.buscarCep(req, reply)
  }
}
```

it works perfectly

My service:

```js
import {feignClient} from "../../shared/feignClient";

export class ViaCepService {
    buscarCep = async (req, reply) => {
        const cep: number = req.params.cep;
        const response: any = await feignClient.get(
            `https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`
        );
        return reply.send(response.data)
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that your private variable goes out of scope (i.e. gets disposed) before the service request can complete.

Comment: check your `dist/` folder, you must initialize the `viaCepService` in a constructor